# can't send mail with swiftmail symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, email, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send an email to swiftmailer with symfony 2.8.
Before 2 months I was able to send emails without problems.
But since one week, I'm not able to send an email.
I tried all these solutions but the issue persists:
- allow less secure app Gmail
- change port from 465 to 587
- trying both mailer_transport SMTP and Gmail
but nothing works.

### Any help, please?

### Error :

Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]
500 Internal Server Error - Swift_TransportException

### code :

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Hello Email')
            ->setFrom('mohamed.maddouri@esprit.tn')
            ->setTo('mohamed.maddouri@esprit.tn')
            ->setBody("test mail")
        ;
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Comment: what is your swiftmailer configuration?

Comment: @goto 
--
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_user: email@email.com
    mailer_password: pwd
    mailer_host: smtp.gmail.co